# php change font of ImageString()

Tags: php, text, textcolor

I am working with my little project which need the following:

- There must be a text at the front of image.
- The text is on centered.

My code follows the instruction but i want to change the font family of the text..

```
ImageString($background, $font_size, $position_center, $position_middle, $text, $textcolor);
```

Here is my full code:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
$background1 = "files/bg.png";
$background = imagecreatefrompng($background1);
$width = 630;
$height = 315;
$text = "EXAMPLE TEXT";
$font_size = 50;
$font_family = "files/tahoma.ttf";
$font_width = ImageFontWidth($font_size);
$font_height = ImageFontHeight($font_size);
$text_width = $font_width * strlen($text);
$position_center = ceil(($width - $text_width) / 2); //CENTER THE TEXT
$text_height = $font_height;
$position_middle = ceil(($height - $text_height) / 2); // MIDDLE THE TEXT
$textcolor = ImageColorAllocate($background, 255, 255, 255);
$image_string = ImageString($background, $font_size, $position_center, $position_middle, $text, $textcolor);
imagepng($background);
imagedestroy($background);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the last 2 statements, $image_string is not used.

Answer (score 0):

[imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) can be used to write text to an image using a TrueType font.
The position parameters for the functino refers to the left edge, to get it centered you need to calculate the correct coordinates, take a look at this php.net comment for how to do it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#83248